# How do I use the FIND function to split a name from an account number in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use a left(find) function to split a name from an account number.

EX: John Smith G123456 -> G123456

Is there a way for excel to detect a string that starts with a specific letter and ends with any digit?

My current implementation has the full string copy pasted from firefox into A1, and then A2 has the following formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("G",A1)-1)
```

This works just fine until I have a name that has G in it.

Thank you!

Comment: Does your values always have this same pattern, e.g.: always ending with an account number? In that case you just need the text after the last space, right?

Comment: I would use find() to get the second space, or the first if there is only one as that is the separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you just want the last word of the input, which would always be the account number, you may try this formula:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)), 100))
```

To isolate the name, you could try removing space followed by the account (the latter which we found using the above formula):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, " " & TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", 100)), 100)), "")
```

Comment: This worked great to get the number! Is there a way to also get the the name?

Comment: I think I just figured it out. I'm just going to store the account number in one cell say B1, and then use: =SUBSTITUTE(A1, B1,"").

Comment: @JackTucker Check my updated answer.  We can try just subtracting off space followed by the account number which we already know how to find.  This would work well assuming that the account number would never appear as part of the name (a reasonable assumption).

Comment: Thanks Tim! That solution is much more robust than my suggestion. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the Account number is always 1 letter 6 digits (7 characters)

you could use
`=MID(A1,LEN(A1)-6,7)` to get the account number

and then `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-8)` for the Name